# Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in

Tags: php, mysql, isset

Buen dia, en el siguiente código verifico que las variables no estén vacías y hago el uso del or para comparar si tiene un valor buscado o es nulo, al realizar eso me sale el error de: **Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in** uso la version de php 7.4, no puedo trabajar solo con el if porque la versión 7.4 muestra **Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in**

```
 <?php if(isset($TipoOperacion['tipo'] == 2) or isset($TipoOperacion['tipo'] == null)): ?>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Monto</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="monto" required="" onkeypress="return PermitirSoloNumeros(event);"  placeholder="Monto de la operaci&oacute;n" autocomplete="off" required/>
</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<?php
else:
endif
?>
<div class="form-group">
<?php if($TipoOperacion['tipo'] == 1): ?>
<button type="submit" name="CierreCaja" class="btn btn-primary">Realizar Cierre de Caja</button>
<?php else:?>
<button type="submit" name="AperturaCaja" class="btn btn-primary">Realizar Apertura de Caja</button>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder entender el error primero hay que entender como y para que existe la función `isset()`

Apelando a la documentación de php:

**isset():**

> isset — Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL
> Si una variable ha sido removida con unset(), esta ya no estará
> definida. isset() devolverá FALSE si prueba una variable que ha sido
> definida como NULL. También tenga en cuenta que un byte NULL ("\0") no
> es equivalente a la constante NULL de PHP.
>
> Si son pasados varios parámetros, entonces isset() devolverá TRUE
> únicamente si todos los parámetros están definidos. La evaluación se
> realiza de izquierda a derecha y se detiene tan pronto como se
> encuentre una variable no definida.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if (isset($var)) {
    echo "Esta variable está definida, así que se imprimirá";
}
```

Por lo que tu condicional se podría refactorizar de esta manera:

```html
<?php

if($TipoOperacion['tipo'] == 2 || empty($TipoOperacion['tipo'])) {
  //to do

}
```

Y si lo que quieres es solamente validar si la variable viene vacia o con datos solo aplicas lo siguiente:

```
if (isset($TipoOperacion['tipo'])) {
    //todo
}
```

Sin embargo el error que te está arrojando refleja que estas trabajando un array, más no una variable, isset se utiliza para  validar el contenido de una variable y no el de una array.

Para arrays puedes usar la siguiente función:

```
array_key_exists
```

> array_key_exists — Verifica si el índice o clave dada existe en el
> array

isset() no retorna TRUE para claves de array que correspondan a un valor NULL, mientras que array_key_exists() si lo hace.

```html
<?php
$TipoOperacion= array('tipo' => null, 'otro' => 4);

// returns false
isset($TipoOperacion['tipo']);

// returns true
array_key_exists('tipo', $TipoOperacion);
?>
```

**Fuente:** https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php

**Fuente:** https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: al probar con la sugerencia del codigo if($TipoOperacion['tipo'] == 2 || empty($TipoOperacion['tipo'])) {
  //to do

}    me muestra lo siguiente Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:

Comment: Entonces primero valida con isset antes de validar el contenido de las variables que por lo que veo es un array. Es importante que leas la documentación de php para que entiendas como se usa la función y la apliques de forma acuada al tipo de dato que estas trabajando.

Comment: Prueba con esta función. array_key_exists('tipo', $TipoOperacion); en vez de utilizar isset. Con isset validas variables, con array_key_exists  puedes validarla existencia de la key de un array.

Comment: intente y muestra lo siguiente  Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Comment: Enviaste los dos parametros dentro de la función el key del array y el array? si es así entonces prueba con un var_dump para que te muestre el contenido del array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($TipoOperacion['tipo'] == 2 )
```

deberia ser

```
if ( isset($TipoOperacion['tipo']) ) {
 if(  $TipoOperacion['tipo'] == 2 ) {
  //tu codigo
 }
}
```

ya que queres saber si la variable $TipoOperacion['tipo'] esta seteada

iseet($var)
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

Creo que le falta cerrar el paréntesis del isset

```
if(isset($TipoOperacion['tipo'] == 2)
```

así debería quedar:

```
if(isset($TipoOperacion['tipo'] ) == 1)
```